# Finding the second derivative of a quotient

Tags: calculus

I am studying maths on my own and have difficulty with this problem:

If = $y=\sqrt{\frac{6x}{x + 2}}$ find the values of $dy/dx$ and $d^2y/dx^2$ when x = 4.

I have calculated $dy/dx$ as $\frac{6}{(x + 2)^22y}$ but cannot calculate
$d^2y/dx^2$

By my calculations the denominator of the first derivative would differentiate to: $2(x +2 )^2.dy/dx + 2y(x + 2$
Then I used the quotient formula $dy/dx = \frac{vdu/dx - udv/dx}{v^2}$ but I cannot get the answer shown in the book, which is -1/32

Comment: You could rewrite this as $\sqrt{6}\left(\frac{x}{x+2}\right)^{1/2} = \sqrt{6}\left(\frac{x+2}{x}\right)^{-1/2} = \sqrt{6}\left(1 + 2x^{-1}\right)^{-1/2}$ and avoid messing with the quotient rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$y=\sqrt{\frac{6x}{x+2}},y^2=\frac{6x}{x+2}=6\left(1-\frac{2}{x+2}\right)$$
now differentiate and you get:
$$2y\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{12}{(x+2)^2}$$
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{6}{(x+2)^2y}$$
so I think you miss out cancelling a factor of $2$ here. You can repeat the same process again and you'll notice that:
$$y\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{6}{(x+2)^2}$$
now differentiate and you get:
$$\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^2+y\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=-\frac{12}{(x+2)^3}$$
now substitute in what you know $\frac{dy}{dx}$ is:
$$\frac{36}{(x+2)^4y^2}+y\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=-\frac{12}{(x+2)^3}$$
and you should be able to get it from here. Alternatively use the chain rule:
$$y=\sqrt{\frac{6x}{x+2}}=\sqrt{u}$$
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{dy}{du}\frac{du}{dx}=\frac1{2\sqrt{u}}\frac{12}{(x+2)^2}=\frac{6}{(x+2)^2}\sqrt{\frac{x+2}{6x}}=6(6x)^{-1/2}(x+2)^{-3/2}$$
Now just use the product rule to find the second derivatve

Comment: @Steve Harris: Henry is using implicit differentation (a really neat way of sometimes avoiding messy algebraic manipulations), which is something you may not have covered yet.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

It is typically a case where it is easier to use logarithmic differentiation:
$$\frac{y'}y=\frac12\Bigl(\frac1x-\frac 1{x+2}\Bigr)=\frac1{x(x+2)}, \quad\text{whence}\quad y'=\frac1{x(x+2)}\,y=\sqrt{\frac 6{x(x+2)^3}}. $$
Similarly
$$\frac{y''}{y'}=-\frac12\biggl(\frac1x+\frac3{x+2}\biggr)=-\frac{2x+1}{x(x+2)},\quad\text{whence} …$$

Comment: I’m afraid I haven’t studied that far ahead Bernard.